# How to style a conversation/dialog using css?

Tags: css

I'm trying to reproduce something like this, but I'm not sure what it's called:

[image]

I'm flexible on the markup, but probably something like this: https://codepen.io/nachocab/pen/LaBwzw

```css
.container  {
  width: 600px;
 }
.speaker {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.speaker::after {
  content: ':';
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="line">
    <span class="speaker">Mary</span><span class="sentence">Hello</span>
  </p>
  <p class="line">
    <span class="speaker">Luke</span><span class="sentence">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      Aenean fringilla pharetra metus id blandit.</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you'll want all character names to be aligned, your best bet is to go for either a plain old table or a more modern CSS grid. A grid would offer more control, perhaps someone who's more experienced with them than I am can propose a solution. Here's how you'd do it with a table. Note that you can always apply table display options to non-table elements if you care about semantics.

```css
.dialogue {
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.dialogue th, .dialogue td {
  padding: 0 0 1em 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.dialogue th {
  text-align: right;
  white-space: pre;
}

.dialogue td {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table class="dialogue">
  <tr class="dialogue-alice">
    <th>Alice Bob: </th>
    <td>Culpa eiusmod qui enim Lorem quis aliquip Lorem id. Incididunt velit fugiat irure tempor ad culpa officia. Laborum magna dolor consequat ipsum aute eiusmod ad eu aute enim magna id non esse. Laborum mollit labore aute consectetur culpa cupidatat. Excepteur esse tempor proident reprehenderit minim duis. Irure eu ullamco ex non dolore sit duis consectetur eu enim officia cillum.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="dialogue-bob">
    <th>Charles Dickens: </th>
    <td>Anim duis laboris commodo mollit incididunt et cupidatat anim aliquip ipsum pariatur veniam. Sint amet esse et esse ea ea consequat ea. Dolore fugiat id et qui esse et ullamco sunt elit velit id.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Note that in my example I aligned the names to the right, but you can align them to the left if that's what you want.

Comment: Great point. That's what I ended up using: https://codepen.io/nachocab/pen/drqMMp

Comment: Cool! Though I'm not sure I'd use a pseudo-element for a colon, as it technically is part of the content. Search engines and screen readers might ignore them, and they are lost when you try to copy-paste.

Answer (score 5):

You probably want something like this, so that the `.speaker` is not overlapping the `.sentence` element.

I've applied `display: flex` to the `.line` so that they sit side by side.

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
}

.speaker {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.speaker::after {
  content: ':';
}

.line {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="line">
    <span class="speaker">Mary</span><span class="sentence">Hello</span>
  </p>
  <p class="line">
    <span class="speaker">Luke</span><span class="sentence">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      Aenean fringilla pharetra metus id blandit.</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: So simple! Thank you

Comment: The sentences only ~fall in line with each other because the names happen to be of similar length. You'll likely want to apply a flex basis to `.speaker` and prevent growing/shrinking. `flex: 0 0 200px`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this code**

Also, you create it use flexbox please learn flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.parent {
  display: table;
}
.message-row {
  display: table-row;
}
.user,
.message {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Mary </td>
    <td>: Hello</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Luke</td>
    <td>: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean fringilla pharetra metus id blandit.</td> 
  </tr>
</table>

 <hr>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="message-row">
    <div class="user">Mary</div>
    <div class="message">: Hello</div>
  </div>
  <div class="message-row">
    <div class="user">Luke</div>
    <div class="message">: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean fringilla pharetra metus id blandit.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```